# Update First Questions Queue feedback to start with "Please edit your question"

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

[image]

Recently I reviewed the first question and selected the "Question needs some code option". The end result was that the user posted code as a comment under the question, which is obviously not the desired result.

Please can all of these options be updated to begin with "Please edit your question" (like the "too broad" option) so that it's completely clear for the user what they need to do.

Comment: Would that include an actual `[edit]` link as well?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Preferably yes, but I don't know if this sort of Advanced Technology is available to us.